# Can't compile on device after swift class integration in my objective-c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a problem that I can't figure it out.

I have an objective-c project and I've needed to integrate a Swift class.
The project runs normally on simulators but I can't compile anymore on device.

Everytime I try to run on device XCode asks me admin credentials:

[Credentials prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Xnr.png)

And when I put my credentials and click "Allow" it asks me again and again.
This problem comes out when the compiler is on "Copying Swift standard libraries".

I've searched on other stackoverflow threads about this credentials issue but nothing helped me.

I've tried to move certificate in keychain from "System" to "login", change trust settings of certificate in "always trust from these applications" and other suggestions found on different thread but nothing worked for me.

I've also tried to remove the Swift class from my project, it asks me credentials ONCE and it COMPILED on device. So, it's definitely Swift the problem.

I don't know what to try more, any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced similar problem. After hours of searchings I found the solution. The reason was in MagicPrefs plugin for System Preferences - it extends the usability of different pointing devices like Magic Mouse and Touch Pad. This alert is a measure of security.
If you do have such software on your Mac, try to disable it for a while.